# Async function is NOT waiting properly

Tags: javascript

So i have a main function that is async and it awaits my other function.

```
main = async () => {
  await this.getResult();
  console.log("end2")
}
```

so here is the getResult function

```
getResult() = async () => {
  const result= await fetch(``, this.requestOptions)
  console.log("end1");
  Promise.all(a.map(async b => {
    console.log("Transaction", trabnsaction);
  }))
}
```

end2 gets printed out first.

Comment: You are not awaiting the promise all.

Comment: What about returning the `Promise.all`?

Comment: Why `(a.map(async b`? There's no `awaiting`.

Comment: it's probably an example, he want to do an async request based on the b value probably.

Comment: Be sure to describe both the _expected_ and _actual_ results.  You say you observe that end2 gets printed out first, but please take the time to say what were you expecting instead and why?  It seems like your misconception may be that Promise.all doesn't return until the promises are resolved, but it doesn't -- it just creates another promise that will resolve when all promises it is given are themselves resolved.  Notably, you discard that promise (it's the return value of Promise.all that you need)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `await` in the `Promise.all` as well.

```js
getResult() = async () => {
    const result= await fetch(``, this.requestOptions)

    console.log("end1");

    await Promise.all(a.map(async b => {
        console.log("Transaction", trabnsaction);

    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `Promise.all`, also you need to return a promise from the `map` method.